# Photos from Mac Library of 2012 to 2023

Tags: mac

I'm trying to open photos from old Mac photo library of 2011-12 in photo library of Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1 but the screen is black white:

[image]

[image]

How to open the file as image view in Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1 photo library?

Comment: How did you Open it? Did it offer to convert it on open? A Library from that long ago would be iPhoto rather than Photos, so would need conversion.

Comment: Try [Wondershare Repairit Photo Repair Tool](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/file-repair/free-tool-to-repair-corrupted-jpeg-photos-for-mac.html).

Comment: I wouldn't do that - could cause all kinds of trouble. The images are probably just fine, but the library structure is either damaged or not in the expected format. Aside from that, the Wondershare app only claims it works up to Catalina.

Comment: Ah - found it. Ventura will no longer convert from iPhoto. You'll need a Mac running something older, depending on what version iPhoto they came from - this looks kinda complicated… First you have to figure out what version of iPhoto last up-converted them - see https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007055

Answer (score 1):

You need something that can up-convert the old iPhoto library structure to the latest Photos structure.

Until Monterey, Photos could do this - so long as the library wasn't *too* old. It was limited to certain iPhoto versions.
Ventura no longer includes the up-converter.
This means you either need to figure out exactly which version of iPhoto they came from & progressively update from there on the appropriate macOS/Photos combination…

… or, apparently this functionality has just been added to Fat Cat's [PowerPhoto](https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/) even apparently the freeware version. [No affiliation & I haven't tried this myself.]
Information from [Tidbits - PowerPhotos Enables Ventura Users to Migrate iPhoto and Aperture Libraries](https://tidbits.com/2023/04/21/powerphotos-enables-ventura-users-to-migrate-iphoto-and-aperture-libraries/)
Background info from [Apple Support Community - How to access Media in iPhoto Libraries on macOS 10.15 or later](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007055)